# Make XML-file inaccessible for user

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess

I am developing a site where students make mathematical exercises. In total there are about 5000 exercises stored in 55 XML-files. The XML-files are stored in a directory in the root of the website. The XML-file is accessed by PHP.
I want to make the XML-file inaccessible for the students. I have made an .htaccess file in the directory of the XML-files:

```
deny from all
```

My PHP codes that access the XML files:

```
if(isset($_GET['m']) && isset($_GET['n']) && isset($_GET['o']))
{
    if(is_numeric($_GET['m'])==false || is_numeric($_GET['n'])==false || is_numeric($_GET['o'])==false)
      //if the variables are not numbers
    {
        header('location: /aanpassen');
        exit();
    }
    if($_GET['m']<1 || $_GET['m']>11)
    {
        header('location: /aanpassen');
        exit();
    }
    if($_GET['n']<1 || $_GET['n']>5)
    {
        header('location: /aanpassen');
        exit();
    }       
        $module = $_GET['m'];
        $niveau = $_GET['n'];
        $nummer = $_GET['o'] - 1;

    //Get the right XML-file

    $urlxml="../xml/module".$module."/niveau".$niveau."/opgave.xml";
        $xml=simplexml_load_file($urlxml);
        $opgave = $xml->opgave[$nummer];
        if(!isset($opgave))//Als de opgave niet bestaat.
        {
            header('location: /aanpassen');
            exit();
        }

    //The rest of the code

    }
```

I tried accessing the file (if I were a student) using Javascript but it returned it was forbidden.

Is there still a security leak?

What is the best way to secure an XML-file?

Comment: The best way is to move it outside the document root. But filtering out with Apache should be fine if you don't remove the `.htaccess` file inadvertently. But I think you're missing `Order allow,deny`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is secure for now. But moving the directory outside the document root would be better. The ".htaccess" can be disabled with a global option (for example to improve performance). In this case your files would be accessible again.

Make sure the application can not write an .htaccess itself.